# How to merge string date and time and convert to date and time w/military format in vb.net?

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, date

I have a table with varchar data type and it stores:

```
stored in a
varchar field ---> date = 05/29/2013
varchar field ---> time = 7:00 PM
```

How do i merge this two in one and use the military time format just like:

```
will be stored in a datetime field  --> 05/29/2013 19:00
```

Will it be the easiest way to compute for time difference in PHP and MySQL? Any suggestion is very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: it is for vb.net, I will use vb.net to store this in mysql. Then i'll use PHP to compute for time difference.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that your dates and times are stored in your database as varchar and not DateTime?  Seems like a flaw in the design to me.

Comment: because i cannot store in my database my specified format just like above. when it inserts in the database it gives: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: DateTime's generally don't have a format when stored in a database.  The format is only important when the DateTime is displayed.  You would probably save yourself a lot of trouble by storing the dates and times as a DateTime and only worry about format when displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) method to convert a string representation of a date/time into a timestamp which can then be used to format it any way you like with the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$dateString = '05/29/2013 7:00 PM';

echo date('m/d/Y H:i', strtotime($dateString));
```

Comment: yeah, i can do that, but how can i do that in vb.net?

Comment: Sorry, I saw this in PHP tag and gave a PHP solution... Don't quote me on this as its been a long time since I've used vb.net, but doesn't the [`DateTime.parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) function do something similar?

Comment: my date and time are in a separate field just like above. so i want to merge this two and put in a single field. I am just confused how it will be done in vb.net.